# update 5 successive row with 5 data in a sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have two table(dic,learnDataTable) in a sqlite database in a android project.In learDataTable there are 5 rows only. My aim is to fetch 5 random data from dic table and update 5 rows of the learnDataTable with this fetched data.
N:B: the structure of dic and learnDataTable is similar and they have two field and these are word as string type and meaning as string type. 
I tried like this.

```
 // fetch 5 random data from dic table
 String sql ="SELECT  * FROM dic ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5" ;

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }

         //now update learnDataTable
         for (int i = 0; i < mCur.getCount(); i++) 
        {
             mCur.moveToPosition(i);

               String word = mCur.getString(0).toString();
               String meaning = mCur.getString(1).toString();

               String sql2 ="update learnDataTable set english='"+word+"',bangla='"+meaning+"'";
                 mDb.execSQL(sql2);               

        }
```

But i know it just update all rows each time. My aim to update learnDataTable with 5 random data from dic table.
How can i do that???

Comment: add `"WHERE rowid = " + i.toString();` to your update clause

Comment: You must have a where clause to specify the rows to update, whatever the criteria needs to be. If you've an ID column, you'll probably want something like "WHERE ID IN (<list of IDs selected>)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
 //Clears learnDataTable:
 mDb.execSQL("DELETE FROM learnDataTable");
 //Insert 5 random rows from dic:
 mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO learnDataTable (english, bangla) SELECT english ,bangla FROM dic ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5");
```

Fast and simple!

Answer (score 0):

Select out the unique **rowid** out from your dic table as well, as it's needed in the update statement.

```
// fetch 5 random data from dic table
String sql = "SELECT rowid, english ,bangla "
            + "FROM dic ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";

    ...

    // now update learnDataTable
    for (int i = 0; i < mCur.getCount(); i++) {
        mCur.moveToPosition(i);

        int id = mCur.getInt(0);
        String word = mCur.getString(1);
        String meaning = mCur.getString(2);

        String sql2 = "update learnDataTable set english='" + word
                + "',bangla='" + meaning + "'" + " WHERE rowid = " + id;
        mDb.execSQL(sql2);

    }
```